# Java Text Coding

Tags: java, string, text

Im trying to figure out is it possible to write a program where when the Text is written is there a way to have a new Line on it for example

```
 the text would read       Hello World,
                           How may I help You
```

with out me having to make 2 strings it should just be one like 
String str = "Hello World, How may I help you";

I feel like i might be over thinking the solution

Comment: Please clarify your question. The text is written where? How? Show some code perhaps.

Comment: Sorry Never mind I just Answered and figure it out I was over thinking it Any way I can remove this question from here

Comment: You could, or you could answer your own question.

Comment: First he should clarify it!

Comment: Freddy, by asking a question on StackOverflow you are asking people people to invest their (spare) time in it. If you find your solution by yourself, that's great! But in such a case is is considered good courtesy to post your answer. We get curious you know. :)  Also, nothing more frustrating than searching for a problem you have, then finding a post describing exactly the same issue as you are having, only to see the OP say: "I solved it already, thanks", without him actually saying *how* he solved it.

Comment: Oh yeah the way I did it was it was simple Like i said I was over thinking it should be String str "Hello World" +"\n"+ "How may I help you";

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use the newline character `\n`. The code would look like this:

```
String str = "Hello World,\nHow may I help you";
```

Comment: Assuming of course that the output is to the console.